# Identifying tables with specific contents in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to find data in a database with hundreds of tables. I am currently "select staring" each table to view their contents, and it is taking forever! Is there a way that I can write a query to filter all of the tables with specific contents? For example, suppose I wanted to find all of the tables that contained "Montana" in any of the columns. Is that possible?

Comment: a business piece of advice/answer - ask your colleagues if they have a 'data model' - you could browse that for likely locations you'd find your data

Comment: @thatjeffsmith this database is for a software that I am using, so who knows how the data model is set up

Comment: name of said software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you loop through all "character"-like columns, you'd do it like this (it also calculates how many times the search string is found in that table/column). I don't have any Virginia, so I'm searching for KING instead.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select table_name, column_name
  5                  from user_tab_columns
  6                  where data_type like '%CHAR%'
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 10                        '  where ' || cur_r.column_name ||' = ' ||
 11                        chr(39) || 'KING' || chr(39)
 12                   into l_cnt;
 13      if l_cnt > 0 then
 14         dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||': '|| l_cnt);
 15      end if;
 16    end loop;
 17  end;
 18  /
EMP.ENAME: 1
V_EMP.ENAME: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: ```set serveroutput on
declare
      l_cnt number;
    begin
      for cur_r in (select table_name, column_name
                    from user_tab_columns
                    where data_type like '%CHAR%'
                   )
      loop
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.table_name ||'  where ' || cur_r.column_name ||' = ' || chr(39) || 'KING' || chr(39)  into l_cnt;
       if l_cnt > 0 then
          dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||'.'|| cur_r.column_name ||': '|| l_cnt);
       end if;
     end loop;
   end;```

Comment: I get an error "missing or invalid operation" when I try to save the procedure

Comment: Save the procedure? How? Where? As you can see, code I posted *works*; I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: what is dbms_output ? That line is where my error is occurring

Comment: It is dbms_output (underline, not dot). It is Oracle's built-in package; its procedure put_line is used to display output on the screen (just like in my example). Which database do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure. I am new to this. I am using Oracle SQL Developer if that answers your question. The dot was a typo when I was typing here; I have it typed correctly in my script.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a tool. Most often it is used along with an Oracle database. You should really know which database you use ... Could you post a screenshot which illustrates your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237905/discussion-between-325-and-littlefoot).

Comment: I opened a chat to show a screenshot

Comment: At the end, it turned out that @325 ran that code in a *project*, instead of a SQL worksheet window. It is an Oracle database (error 325 got was ORA-00922).